# Python Requests - can't get POST form response (only returns form)

Tags: web-scraping

I'm trying to use Python's Requests module to fill out a POST form, then get the output. A lot of websites seem to use this code as an example. However, it keeps only returning the form. I created a simple POST form, and it seems to be returning the form itself too. Here is the Python code:

```
import requests

url = 'http://127.0.0.1/test.html'
data = { 'name': 'Test','age': '52'}

r = requests.post(url, data=data)
print(r.text)
```

The 'test' HTML form:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action='test.php' method='post'>
            <input name='name' type='text'>
            <br>
            <input name='age' type='text'>
            <br>
            <input name='calculate' type='submit' value='Submit test'>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The 'test' PHP form:

```
<?php

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];

    echo "$name, $age";

?>
```

I can confirm that the form itself works without any problems from the browser. Does anyone know what's causing this problem?

Comment: why are you posting to a html page? Sounds like you just need to change that to be the .PHP page.

Comment: Actually not a Python question in any way (nor a php one one FWIW) - you're just posting to the wrong url.

Comment: typo's are not real questions and it should really be closed/deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly post to the php page.

```
import requests

url = 'http://127.0.0.1/test.php'
data = { 'name': 'Test','age': '52'}

r = requests.post(url, data=data)
print(r.text)
```

Based on @WeavingBird1917's Comment :

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.mso.anu.edu.au/cgi-bin/ephem.cgi'
data = { 'action': 'display','date': 'today','latitude':'-35:19:12','longitude':'149:00:30','timezone':'+10:00'}


r = requests.post(url, data=data)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: @WeavingBird1917 can you check now please?

Comment: Ah! Cool. No problem :)